# Additive energy and uniquely representable elements

Tags: additive-combinatorics, sumsets

Suppose that $A$ is a finite, nonempty set in an abelian group. If there is a group element with a unique representation as $a-b$ with $a,b\in A$, then none of $A-A$ and $2A$ are small:
$$ \min\{|A-A|,|2A|\} \ge 2|A|-1; $$
this is almost immediate for the difference set, while the sumset case is a nontrivial result due to Kemperman and Scherk.

I need an analogue of this result for the additive energy of $A$ defined by
$$ E(A):=\{(a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4)\in A^4\colon a_1+a_2=a_3+a_4\}. $$
A straightforward application of the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality gives the well-known estimate $E(A)\ge|A|^4/|2A|$. How small can $E(A)$ be given that there is an element with a unique representation as $a-b$ with $a,b\in A$? Given that there are "many" uniquely representable elements?

What I would need is an explicit estimate that works starting with very small values of $|A|$, not involving excessively large constants and the $O/o$-notation. Even an improvement by a lower-order term can be helpfull.

Comment: Additive energy $E(A)$ tends to behave inversely to the sumset size $|2A|$.  So wouldn't the analogue of a lower bound on $|2A|$ be an *upper* bound on $E(A)$ rather than a lower bound?

Comment: If $G = \mathbb Z/(3n)$ is a finite abelian group, and $A$ consists of all the multiples of $3$ together with $1$,  then $1$ has a unique representation as a difference (in fact, every element that's not a multiple of $3$ does) but the additive energy of $A$ is at least $n^3 = (|A| -1 )^3$. So the additive energy can be very large under this condition.

Comment: @TerryTao: I have to think more about the ideology, but anyway, the question is as stated.

Comment: @WillSawin: $(|A|-1)^3$ is about twice larger than $|A|^4/|2A|$, a way better than I need.

Comment: If $A$ is $n$ random elements in $\mathbb R$ then $E(A) = 2n^2- n $,  $|2A|$ is $n (n+1)/2$,  so $|A|^4/ 2|A|$ is $ 2n^3/ (n+1) = 2n^2 - 2n + 2 + O(1/n)$, which barely differs from $E(A)$. Of course some (in fact, every) element is uniquely represented. Is this OK for you?

Comment: @WillSawin: $E(A)\ge|A|^4/|2A|+N/2$, where $N$ is the number of uniquely represented elements, would certainly suffice. Maybe, the estimate $E(A)\ge|A|^4/|2A|+|A|$ that you mentioned will also do, not sure.

Comment: Would a bound like $E(A)\geq \lvert A\rvert^4/\lvert A-A\rvert+N/2$ suffice? Or is the use of the sumset in the lower bound important?

Comment: @Thomas Bloom: With the difference set this would be easy, but I need it with the sumset.